# Associations are not loaded when selecting fields

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp, cakephp-3.0

I am having some trouble trying to fetch associated models when selecting fields. My version of CakePHP is 3.0beta2.

Three MYSQL tables that are relevant to this question:

```
users:
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`username` varchar(30) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`password` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`role` varchar(20) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
... (more information)
```

-

```
presets:
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`name` varchar(60) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
... (more information)
```

-

```
favorites:
`id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`preset_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
`created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
```

My associations are defined as shown below:

```
// From FavoritesTable.php
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->belongsTo('Users');
    $this->belongsTo('Presets');
}

// From PresetsTable.php
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->belongsTo('Users');
    $this->hasMany('Favorites');
}

// From UsersTable.php
public function initialize(array $config) {
    $this->hasMany('Presets');
    $this->hasMany('Favorites');
}
```

What I'm trying to achieve is:

1. Load all the user information for the currently logged in user
2. Load all the favorites that this user has
3. Create a new field that transforms the `created` field (a timestamp) into a date
4. For each favorite, load the associated preset data

This is the code that I use to do that:

```
// From UsersController.php
public function favorites() {

    $userId = $this->Auth->user('id');

    $user = $this->Users->find('all')
        ->where(['id' => $userId])
        ->contain([
            'Favorites' => function($q) {
                return $q
                    ->select(['id', 'preset_id', 'user_id', 'created', 'date' => 'DATE(created)'])
                    ->order(['Favorites.created' => 'DESC']);
            },
            'Favorites.Presets',
        ])
        ->first();

    $this->set('user', $user);
}
```

The problem is: when I use the `select` method as in the code above, the `Favorites.Presets` association is not loaded, so `$user['favorites'][0]['preset']` is always `null`.

But if I comment out the select method (thus selecting all fields and not retrieving `DATE(created)`, the association is loaded and I can access the information from the presets table.

Could this be a bug or am I doing something wrong?
Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need to call `->autoFields(true)` after `select()`. This is required if you expect all other fields to be selected. This could probably be seen as a bug, try opening a ticket in github.

Comment: That solved it. I would have never found that by myself.
Thanks!

Comment: Not a bug. By design, using a select with contain limits those. From the manual `If you have limited the fields you are loading with select() but also want to load fields off of contained associations, you can use autoFields()` (http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#passing-conditions-to-contain)